# Method declaration is compatible but PHP complains

Tags: php, splobjectstorage

So I have this class:

```
class JSObjectStorage extends \SplObjectStorage
{

    /**Adds a JavaScript object inside the storage, and optionally associate it to some data.*/    
    public function attach($javaScript, $data = null){}

    /**Removes the object from the storage.*/
    public function detach($javaScript){}

    /**Adds all objects-data pairs from a different JavaScriptBundle storage in the current storage.*/
    public function addAll(\SplObjectStorage $storage){}

    /**Removes objects contained in another storage from the current storage.*/
    public function removeAll(\SplObjectStorage $storage){}

    /**Removes all objects except for those contained in another storage from the current storage.*/
    public function removeAllExcept(\SplObjectStorage $storage){}

    /**Alias to JSObjectStorage::attach. */    
    public function offsetSet($javaScript, $data = null){}

    /**Alias to JSObjectStorage::detach*/
    public function offsetUnset($javaScript){}

    /**Returns the data associated with an object in the storage.*/
    public function offsetGet($javaScript){}

    /**This method calculates an identifier for the objects added to JSObjectStorage object.*/
    public function getHash($javaScript){}
}
```

and this is the SplObjectStorage:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

As you can see they are identical but when I instantiate JSObjectSTorage, I get the following error:

> Strict standards: Declaration of
>   MOWAFW\Core\Type\JavaScript\JSObjectStorage::addAll() should be
>   compatible with that of SplObjectStorage::addAll() in
>   /Users/******/JSObjectStorage.php on line 175

And this happens to removeAll() and removeAllExcept().

Any ideas?!

---

I'm using:

```
PHP 5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 20 2012 22:55:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Just tried with 5.4.8 and your code works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure this does not happen with the `removeAll()` method also? If it does, then I would suspect type hinting for the parameters might be causing it - maybe an incompatibility with your PHP version, not sure though.

Comment: @inhan Yes, like I stated in the question this also happens with removeAll() and removeAllExcept().
Removing the type hint does not fix the problem.

Comment: I must have missed that, sorry. Then, apparently it's related to type hinting. Looks like [**bug #40653**](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/40653) despite version difference.

Comment: @inhan Ah! Bloody hell!!! That's some really nasty bug.
At least there's a workaround, but even so... Well, thank you very much. Make an answer and the "green tick" is yours.

Comment: Sure. Although it's not a solution I'm glad it explains the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone posted a bug report entitled ["Namespace interfaces not working due to type hinting issues" (Bug #40653)](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/40653), which looks like your case despite the PHP version difference (it reads ***v. < 5.3.7***).